# vb 2012 module (F as Form)

Tags: vb.net

my module code is

```
Module print
 Sub Pad (F as form)
  F.Textbox1.text = "testing"
 End sub
End module
```

is there a way to use the "print.pad" to my 3 form (FrmNew,FrmOld,FrmAdmin) like this

```
Public Class FrmNew

 Private Sub FrmNew_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
  Print.Pad(Me)
 End Sub

End Class
```

Because in VBA it work.

VBA MODULE code (Module name Printt)

```
Sub Pad(f As Form)
 f.Text0 = "testing"
End Sub
```

VBA FORM Code (Form name Form1)

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
 Call Printt.Pad(Form_Form1)
End Sub
```

or any way around to do it. tnx in advance...

Comment: do all your forms have Textbox1 on them

Comment: yes there is textbox1

Comment: then create a from with text box and Inherit other forms from it

Comment: or directly pass text box to method - Sub Pad (Textbox1 as textbox)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and make the subject more meaningful. "vb 2012 module (F as Form)" is absolute nonsense to everyone but you, and will have no value in a search result for future users of this site. Your title should have content relevant to what your question is asking that everyone can understand. Thanks.

Comment: can u show me a sample code. I am very new at vb.net and my English is bad. tnx

Comment: sory ken white i really don't know how to ask this, only explain it. if i try to edit it. it may become very long. is that ok?

Comment: @user2184608 are you trying to show `"testing"` in your `FrmNew` 's `Load` Event  ??

Comment: yes i am. but not only on load. also when i click a button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Module print
  Public Sub Pad (ByVal txtControl As TextBox)
  txtControl.Text = "testing"
 End sub
End module
```

and call like

```
 Public Class FrmNew
        Private Sub FrmNew_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
          Print.Pad(textbox1)
        End Sub
End Class
```

- here `textbox1` is the control in your `FrmNew`,In this you want show `textbox1.text = "testing"`

Comment: sorry for the late reply. your code work perfect. thank you so much.